# rails devise gem redirect loop

Tags: redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using the devise gem with a rails 4.1.4 app, and needed to add some custom key-value pairs in a session variable right after a user has signed in.

I overrode the following methods 
`after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`

`after_sign_up_path_for(resource)`

`after_update_path_for(resource)`

`after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)` methods as prescribed here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Yet, on signing in, I enter the `after_sign_in_path_for` multiple times, with the following output:

`Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-08 22:56:45 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML`
`User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1`
`Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)`

each time, before finally redirecting me to the root path. (The browser temporarily shows the redirect loop error message before redirecting me to the root).

EDIT:

So turns out that since I have 2 different devise models (users and admins), this line of code in `after_sign_in_path_for`:

`sign_in_url = url_for(:action => 'new', :controller => 'sessions', :only_path => false, :protocol => 'http')`

is creating the url `"http://localhost:3000/admins/sign_in"` instead of `"http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in"`

How do I make url_for default to the users model and not the admin model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into this issue myself.  For whatever reason, `url_for` seems to default to the admin (no idea why)  The good news is that you don't have to use `url_for` to accomplish this.

**Instead,** get rid of

```
sign_in_url = url_for(:action => 'new', :controller => 'sessions', :only_path => false, :protocol => 'http')
```

and replace

```
if request.referer == sign_in_url
```

with

```
if request.referer == new_user_session_url
```

The helper makes your code cleaner and allow you to specify which devise model you want.

Comment: haha thanks I did something similar and had totally forgotten about this!